# Is there a way to increment IPv6 address routing prefix block using python?

Tags: python-3.x, scapy

Is there a way to increment IPv6 address (routing prefix block only) using python ?

2001:db8:**3333**:4444:5555:6666:7777:8888

3333 should be incremented by 5333 (2000+)

On each iterations value should be 2000+,

Inside for loop I tried incrementing ipv6 address by,

addr1 = ipaddress.IPv6Address('2001:db8:3333:4444:5555:6666:7777:8888')
addr1 = addr1 + 1000000
addr1
IPv6Address('2001:db8:3333:4444:5555:6666:7786:cac8')

Answer (score 0):

You may cast the IPv6 address to int and add to address just like that

```
addr1 = ipaddress.IPv6Address('2001:db8:3333:4444:5555:6666:7777:8888')
addr1 += int(ipaddress.IPv6Address('0000:000:2000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000'))
```